# Change of checkbox doesn't trigger function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 checkboxes that one selects the other.
Checkbox1 has a change event. However, when I check checkbox1 via checkbox2, the event on checkbox1 is not being triggered.

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deligeli/s6fe9/809/).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#check1").change(arrangeWindow);
   $("#check2").click(function(){
      $("#check1").prop("checked", this.checked);
   });
});

function arrangeWindow() {
    console.log("Missing my baby");
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="check1" value="value" />
<label for="chk">Checkbox 1</label>

<input type="checkbox" id="check2" value="value" />
<label for="chk">Checkbox 2 </label>
```

I can call arrangeWindow from check2 click function, but that's not smart.

How can I trigger the change event upon changing it via jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Programmatically changing the checked property does not raise an event on the element. If you need that behaviour you can use `trigger('change')` manually:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#check1").change(arrangeWindow);
  $("#check2").change(function(){
    $("#check1").prop("checked", this.checked).trigger('change');
  });
});

function arrangeWindow() {
  console.log("Missing my baby");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="check1" value="value" />
<label for="chk">Checkbox 1</label>

<input type="checkbox" id="check2" value="value" />
<label for="chk">Checkbox 2 </label>
```

Also note that you should always use the `change` event when dealing with checkboxes and radios for accessibility reasons, as that event can be fired on the element using the keyboard.

Comment: why is change preferred over click?

Comment: Also `jQ.change()` could be sued instead of `jQ.trigger('change')` but it could come under _Developers preference.._

Comment: @Rayon Yeah, that's more of a preference. I prefer `trigger('event')` as the purpose of the call is clearer.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan there is something weird with it. If my arrangeWindow() action takes half a second, the checkbox will be checked ONLY after the action is completed. this is very annoying. any way that it will first select the checkbox and then trigger the change?

Comment: Put the call to `arrangeWindow()` in a `setTimeout`, like this: `setTimeout(arrangeWindow, 1);`